# How to retrieve selectedRows from a material-table in React

Tags: reactjs, material-table

I have a material table and I use selection and filtering.

Above my material table I have a button that should "send" the selected rows to its parent if you click on it.

How can I retrieve the selected Rows though? I know I can do

```
const [selectedRows, setSelectedRows] = useState([]);


<MaterialTable 
...
onSelectionChange={(rows) => {
   setSelectedRows(rows);
}}

... />
```

But the setSelectedRows results in the Table to be rerendered and then all my filters are gone. I know I could store filters in a state too , but this sounds like way too much overhead for just the simpe question to retrieve the selectedRows at a certain point in time.

Any easy suggestions?

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 1):

Use the components prop and lift the FilterRow component into parent state like below. The filter values will persist.

```
import MaterialTable, { MTableFilterRow } from 'material-table';

const Parent = () => {
  const [components, whatever] = useState({
    FilterRow: props => <MTableFilterRow {...props} />,
  });

  const [columns] = useState([
    { title: "Name", field: "name" },
    { title: "Pet", field: "pet" }
  ]);

  const [data] = useState([
    { name: "Jim", pet: "Dog" },
    { name: "Tom", pet: "Horse" },
    { name: "Susan", pet: "Rat" },
    { name: "Penny", pet: "Cat" }
  ]);


  return (
    <MaterialTable
      columns={columns}
      data={data}
      components={components}
    />
  );
}
``
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it stil doesnt work for me unless I did it wrong. Here is a codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-https-8bfms

Simple filter by anything and then hit a checkbox of one of the remaining rows. See that the filter disappears. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

Add a ref to the component

```
<MaterialTable
  tableRef={tableRef}
```

you can get selected rows with

```
tableRef.current.dataManager.data.filter(o => o.tableData.checked)
```

Answer (score 0):

we can use **onRowClick** property to retrieve clicked/seleted row data in the following way

```
<MaterialTable 
    onRowClick={useCallback((event, data) => setSelectedRow(data))}
    options={{
        exportButton: false,
        filtering: false,
        paging: false,
        search: true,
    }}
    columns={[
        { field: 'shortName', title: 'Short Name' },
        { field: 'entityStatus.code', title: 'Status'},
    ]}
    data={lookUpClients}
    title={''}
/>
```